# Receive external requests on firebase functions without cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

Hello Evereyone I'm currently having some issues with the backend part of a firebase app.

I have some functions that are exported in the main js, and these functions receive incoming post requests from the frontend (in another server). The thing is that during the tests on my localhost they work perfectly but now in the servers I've got this error message in the front-end

> [Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (receiveSolar, line 0)
>   [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us-central1-myserverurl.cloudfunctions.net/receiveSolar. Preflight response is not successful

Now I'm exporting the function with this code in the index.js:

```
exports.receiveSolar = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
var object = request.body;
solar.otrafuncion(object.solar).then(objetoSolar =>{
    response.send(objetoSolar);
  });


});
```

and after reading and doing some research, I did added this lines to the firebase.json

```
  "hosting": {
"public": "public",
"headers": [ {
  "source" : "*",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
} ]
}]
}
```

Bus still I get no response

So how may I enable my back-end to receive and respond to the front-end

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, CORS isn't simple, so don't worry that you're having problems :)

Your *request* actually consists of two separate requests - the GET/POST that you coded in the client JS, and a CORS preflight OPTIONS request - this 'preflight' request is made under-the-covers by the browser, immediately before it makes your GET request to the server. The OPTIONS request will include some `Access-Control-Request-*` headers, as well as an `Origin` request header.

The response to the OPTIONS request needs to include some other `Access-Control-*`response headers (in addition to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). If you don't return those other headers for the OPTIONS response, the browser won't actually run the GET request.

So...

You need to update your firebase.json to return those other CORS headers for the preflight OPTIONS request, in addition to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Specifically, **at a minimum**, you need to return the following additional response headers when request method is OPTIONS:

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {value of Access-Control-Request-Headers request header}`
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: {value of Access-Control-Request-Method request header}`

So if the OPTIONS request arrives at the backend with the following request headers:

`Origin: https://www.yourpage.com`

`Access-Control-Request-Method: GET`

`Access-Control-Request-Headers: header1, header2, header3`

then your **response** to that OPTIONS request must include the following **response headers**:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.yourpage.com`

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET`

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: header1, header2, header3`

For the actual GET request, you only need to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header (as you are currently doing).